# Updating R on a Debian 7 Server

Tags: debian, r

I was wondering what the best way to go about updating a semi old version of R to the latest version, which I believe is 3.2.2-1. I havent needed it for a while but now will need it more with a few features that are only on the latest version.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please [edit] your question and tell us which version of Debian you are running and  why you don't just `sudo apt-get install r-base`. Do you need a newer version that what is in the repos?

Comment: CRAN has R Debian packages maintained by Dirk E. Just google "CRAN Debian".